# JVM heap stuck at 2g even when started with -Xmx 3G

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory

We have a weird issue with a java process.
It was started with -Xmx3G , and at some point it started throwing :

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Checking the GC logs around the time the error is thrown, the heap size seems stuck at 2G ?

```
...
12893.533: [Full GC 2248110K->2248109K(2315776K), 0.4723440 secs]
212894.006: [Full GC 2248110K->2248109K(2315776K), 0.4823290 secs]
212894.490: [Full GC 2248110K->2248110K(2315776K), 0.4642130 secs]
212894.955: [Full GC 2248114K->2248112K(2315776K), 0.4866180 secs]
...
```

What are the possible reasons that could explain this ?

Comment: Just to mention that there were around 5G RAM free on the server at the time this happened. So not all RAM was used at that point

Comment: check if you are using 32-bit or 64-bit JVM

Comment: post more of the GC log, what you posted doesn't show the young gen size. and you should figure out how large the allocation at the callsite throwing the OOME is.

Comment: We're on 64bit JVM.
Below are some more GC logs, specifically at the time when Full GC started (proc was started with "-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -Xmx3G"

`187964.806: [GC 2258418K->2111449K(2336768K), 0.0912450 secs]
188147.174: [GC 2260441K->2114356K(2339840K), 0.0390060 secs]
188178.455: [GC 2137835K->2113657K(2315776K), 0.0527470 secs]
188178.508: [Full GC 2113657K->2090890K(2315776K), 2.9901030 secs]
188328.712: [Full GC 2241930K->2095322K(2315776K), 0.5937130 secs]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is major GC log, which collects the full heap.

It is reasonable that 3G heap but showing about 2.3G in GC log, because the heap is comprised by many parts not only young and old generations but also perm/virtual which are not collected by GC [hotspot VM generations](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html#generation_sizing.total_heap).

The error is caused by that heap is full but GC cannot collect any objects, so larger heap needed or you may have to resize the heap (so young/old generations have larger space). To verify if there is any setting problems, simply using -Xmx5G to see if heap is still stuck at 2G (which should not happen).